# Could this exception depend on an HTTP request timeout?

Tags: c#, httprequest

I am pretty new in **C#** (I came from Java) and I have the following problem.

I have an application that have to download this XML file and then parse it: http://static.nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cpe/dictionary/official-cpe-dictionary_v2.3.xml

The problem is that **SOMOTIMES** during the download is thrown the following excpetion (only sometimes, in some case it work fine, in other case the exception is throwned)

> **{"Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."}**

As you can see here this file is very big, infact it weighs **19.46MB**: http://nvd.nist.gov/cpe.cfm

To download this file, into my code, I have something like it:

A **Program** class that contains the **main()** method:

```
namespace ImportCPE
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ImportCPE task = new ImportCPE("DefaultConnection");
            task.start(new Uri("http://static.nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cpe/dictionary/official-cpe-dictionary_v2.3.xml"));
        }
    }
}
```

The **ImportCPE** class extends this class **ImportBase.ImportBase** that contains all the base import functions including downloading a file from a source XML data represented as a URL.

So into my **ImportBase** class I have the following code that download the XML file into a string object:

```
string esito;
esito = downloadXML(sourceFile, new System.IO.FileInfo(".\\temp.xml"));
```

and this is the code of the **downloadXML()** method (that is always defined inside the same **ImportBase** class):

```
    private string downloadXML(Uri sourceFile, System.IO.FileInfo destinationFile)
    {

        //  sourceXML = destinationFile;
        //return true;


        System.Net.WebRequest myRequest;
        myRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(sourceFile);
        //if (bProxy)
        //{
        //    myRequest.Proxy = wp;
        //}
        myRequest.Timeout = 15000;

        System.Net.WebResponse myResponse = null;
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = null;
        System.IO.FileStream destStream = null;
        try
        {
            myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();


            if (destinationFile.Exists)
            {
                destinationFile.Delete();
            }

            destStream = destinationFile.Create();


            reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            reader.BaseStream.CopyTo(destStream);

            //html = reader.ReadToEnd();

            sourceXML = destinationFile;

        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (myResponse != null)
            {
                myResponse.Close();
            }
            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.Close();
            }

            if (destStream != null)
            {
                destStream.Close();
            }


        }
        return "";
    }
```

Using the Visual Sturio **debugger** it seems to me to understand that the problem occur when it try to perform the following line into the **downloadXML()** method:

```
 myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
```

that catch the following exception: **{"The operation has timed out"}**

So what is the problem? Could be that the setted timeout is to short because the file is too big? So sometimes can download it and in some other case can't?

Increasing the request timeout maybe I could solve this issue?

Setted by:

```
myRequest.Timeout = 15000;
```

Comment: "Increasing the request timeout maybe I could solve this issue?" Did you try that?

Comment: the code is not mine (I am studying it to modify it in the future) and before change something I prefer ask :-P

Comment: Set your timeout to Timeout.Infinite and tell us if it solved the problem